# Troubles with Subscript out of range (Error 9)

Tags: excel, vba

I've read a number of previous posts about this error.  An answer has appeared a few times noting that, essentially, VBA can't find the object I'm trying to point it to.  I've checked multiple times, and the names are correct (as far as I can tell).  I have also been testing this little macro on a different machine prior to this and nothing was wrong.

My code is fairly long (for me) and I'm happy to admit it's the rambling of an amateur.  I've dumped the whole thing in but my problems happen immediately at the top where the program cannot find the ISRTrack workbook and then subsequently the same thing throughout - the ISRTrack workbook can never be found.

I do not understand.  I have a similar process where I open two workbooks at the same time and run a macro and they copy and paste to each other - everyone's happy - granted it's not this ISRTrack workbook.  For some reason this just doesn't work...

Are there other reasons that this error might come up that I'm not thinking of?

Please and thank you in advance.

```
Sub ISRtoTable()

'check if ISR already exists

Dim ISR_Check As String

Set wISRSTC = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete")
Set wISRTLD = Workbooks("ISRTrack").Worksheets("ListData")
Set wISRIT = Workbooks("ISRTrack").Worksheets("ISR_Tracker")

wISRSTC.Range("C51").Copy _
    wISRTLD.Range("L19")

ISR_Check = wISRTLD.Range("L20")

If ISR_Check = False Then

'Dim for insertion of row into ISR_Tracker sheet
Dim the_sheet As Worksheet
Dim table_list_object As ListObject
Dim table_object_row As ListRow

'Dim for insertion of row into ISR_Notes sheet
Dim Nthe_sheet As Worksheet
Dim Ntable_list_object As ListObject
Dim Ntable_object_row As ListRow

'Dim for insertion of row into ISR_Financial sheet
Dim Fthe_sheet As Worksheet
Dim Ftable_list_object As ListObject
Dim Ftable_object_row As ListRow

Dim ISR_Yr As String
Dim DT As String
Dim ISR_No As String
Dim FY_One As String
Dim FY_Two As String
Dim FY_Three As String

'Put date and time from ISRT into variable
DT = Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("ISR_Tracker").Range("A3")

'Put fiscal year fields into variables for later ISR transferring
FY_One = Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("List_Data").Range("K13")
FY_Two = Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("List_Data").Range("K14")
FY_Three = Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("List_Data").Range("K15")

'Add a row to the ISR_Tracker sheet table
Set the_sheet = Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("ISR_Tracker")
Set table_list_object = the_sheet.ListObjects(1)
Set table_object_row = table_list_object.ListRows.Add

'place the year from the List_Data table into a variable
ISR_Yr = Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("List_Data").Range("K8")

'Generate an ISR number and put it into the newly created row in the table located in ISR_Tracker
With table_object_row

    If (.Range(1).Row - Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("List_Data").Range("K9")) < 10 Then
        .Range(1) = ISR_Yr & "00" & (.Range(1).Row - Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("List_Data").Range("K9"))
    Else
        If (.Range(1).Row - Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("List_Data").Range("K9")) < 100 Then
            .Range(1) = ISR_Yr & "0" & (.Range(1).Row - Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("List_Data").Range("K9"))
        Else
            .Range(1) = ISR_Yr & (.Range(1).Row - Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("List_Data").Range("K9"))
        End If
    End If

    .Range(2) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("G4")
    .Range(3) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("D18")
    .Range(4) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("D20")
    .Range(5) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("D10")
    .Range(8) = "IMPORTED"

    'Import ISR number back into ISR Template
    ISR_No = .Range(1)
    ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("C51") = ISR_No

End With

'Add a row to the ISR_Notes sheet table
Set Nthe_sheet = Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("Notes")
Set Ntable_list_object = Nthe_sheet.ListObjects(1)
Set Ntable_object_row = Ntable_list_object.ListRows.Add

'Populate new ISR_Notes table with a note about a new ISR being imported
With Ntable_object_row

    .Range(1) = ISR_No
    .Range(2) = DT
    .Range(3) = Application.UserName
    .Range(4) = "New ISR Imported"

End With

'Add a row to the Financial sheet table to import fiscal year one - if one exists
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("E41") > 0 Then

    Set Fthe_sheet = Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("Financial")
    Set Ftable_list_object = Fthe_sheet.ListObjects(1)
    Set Ftable_object_row = Ftable_list_object.ListRows.Add

        With Ftable_object_row

            .Range(1) = ISR_No
            .Range(2) = DT
            .Range(3) = Application.UserName
            .Range(4) = "N/A"
            .Range(5) = FY_One
            .Range(6) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("E41")
            .Range(7) = "ESTIMATE"
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("H47") = "Yes" Then
                .Range(8) = "Recoverable"
            Else
            End If

        End With

Else
End If

'Add a row to the Financial sheet table to import fiscal year two - if one exists
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("G41") > 0 Then

    Set Fthe_sheet = Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("Financial")
    Set Ftable_list_object = Fthe_sheet.ListObjects(1)
    Set Ftable_object_row = Ftable_list_object.ListRows.Add

        With Ftable_object_row

            .Range(1) = ISR_No
            .Range(2) = DT
            .Range(3) = Application.UserName
            .Range(4) = "N/A"
            .Range(5) = FY_Two
            .Range(6) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("E41")
            .Range(7) = "ESTIMATE"
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("H47") = "Yes" Then
                .Range(8) = "Recoverable"
            Else
            End If

        End With

Else
End If


'Add a row to the Financial sheet table to import fiscal year three - if one exists
If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("I41") > 0 Then

    Set Fthe_sheet = Workbooks("ISRT").Worksheets("Financial")
    Set Ftable_list_object = Fthe_sheet.ListObjects(1)
    Set Ftable_object_row = Ftable_list_object.ListRows.Add

        With Ftable_object_row

            .Range(1) = ISR_No
            .Range(2) = DT
            .Range(3) = Application.UserName
            .Range(4) = "N/A"
            .Range(5) = FY_Three
            .Range(6) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("E41")
            .Range(7) = "ESTIMATE"
            If ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("ISR - CPDB Staff to Complete").Range("H47") = "Yes" Then
                .Range(8) = "Recoverable"
            Else
            End If

        End With

Else
End If


'Bottom of check for existing ISR
Else
    MsgBox ("This ISR number already exists in the table.  Operation cancelled.")
    Exit Sub
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I would like to add that I am aware there is inconsistency within the code with respect to references.  I've been messing with only the first few lines to try to clear the error before fixing everything else.

Comment: Worth noting that whether or not `Workbooks("fileNameNoExtension")` works or not (at least on Windows) is dependent on the Windows Explorer "Hide extensions for known file types" setting (on the View tab in the Folder Options dialog).  If this is unchecked, you need to include the extension - if it's not checked then you don't.  Note it *always* works if you just include the extension by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just tried on a piece of my own code - adding the file extension to the name (.xlsx or whatever format your file is in) fixed a similar issue for me.  So "ISRTrack.xlsx" in your case.

Comment: Hmm... tentatively good I'm past this error... excuse me while I cry myself to sleep.  Will iron it out fully and see if it's gone for good.